# How do I make a rectangle attach to a circle and spin along with it in Swift, SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

So I've been trying to recreate something like the game "aa" where an "Arrow" shoots at a circle and attaches to it and spins along with it. I've managed to make the arrow attach the arrow to the circle but it doesn't spin it just stays on its position being attached to the circle. I started coding about a week ago and I can't figure out the solution to it. Here is my didBeginContact func

```
   func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        let firstBody = contact.bodyA
        let secondBody = contact.bodyB

        if firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.Circle && secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.Arrow || firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.Arrow && secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.Circle {

            var Joint = SKPhysicsJointSpring.joint(withBodyA: Arrow.physicsBody!, bodyB: Circle.physicsBody!, anchorA: Arrow.position, anchorB: Circle.position)

            self.physicsWorld.add(Joint)

        }
    }
```

Also that's how I made the circle spin
`Circle.run(SKAction .rotate(byAngle: 9999, duration: 5000))`

I wonder if there is any other way to make it keep spinning at all times other than just putting a very long duration.

Comment: I changed Arrow.position and Circle.position to anchorPoint which does make it spin along with the circle but it doesn't stay in a horizontal position it just kinda does whatever it wants to.

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out myself.

`var Joint = SKPhysicsJointSpring.joint(withBodyA: Arrow.physicsBody!, bodyB: Circle.physicsBody!, anchorA: Arrow.position, anchorB: Circle.position)`

Changed to

`var Joint = SKPhysicsJointFixed.joint(withBodyA: Circle.physicsBody!, bodyB: Arrow.physicsBody!, anchor: Circle.position)`